# Cannot get Description field of a Jenkins Job or Parameter

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Is it possible to obtain the Job Description or the Job Parameter Description in run-time or later like the BUILD_ID or JOB_NAME?

I search for plugins or workarounds and nothing.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try checking which global variables are available? For example if you use Jenkins pipeline you can check:
https://<<yourjenkinsdomain>>/pipeline-syntax/globals#env

and from there you can use ${currentBuild.description} and/or ${currentBuild.number}. 

If you want the JOB_NAME the correct syntax should be ${env.JOB_NAME} or ${JOB_NAME} in runtime (at least in our configuration).

Comment: There is no global/env variable for Job/parameter description

Answer (score 1):

This would be Tip/workaround

```
https://<<yourjenkinsdomain>>/job/<<yourjobname>>/configure (will open the configuration of your job)
```

However

```
https://<<yourjenkinsdomain>>/job/<<yourjobname>>/config.xml (will give the job configuration in an xml format)
```

You can download this xml via curl at run time or using jenkins cli and use a grep with -B option to find description per value.

Considering you have copied the with name "config.xml"

```
cat config.xml | grep -B 1 "description"
```

Will give you description and build parameter name

```
 Grep command 
 -B NUM, --before-context=NUM
          Print  NUM  lines  of  leading  context  before  matching lines.
          Places  a  line  containing  a  group  separator  (--)   between
          contiguous  groups  of  matches.  With the -o or --only-matching
          option, this has no effect and a warning is given.
```

Sample output :

```
cat config.xml | grep -B 1 "description"

<actions/>
<description>Job description : Automation </description>
--
<name>branch</name>
<description>mandatory parameter , used for automation</description>
```

--

Alternative :

jenkins cli has an option to set value

```
set-build-description   Sets the description of a build.
set-build-parameter Update/set the build parameter of the current build in progress. [deprecated]
```

you can write a small script and get the values into variables and use them

Comment: Despite is an workaround, seems to be possible, getting config xml. Not the most clean solution but thanks.